# Can't SSH to remote host after Rsync

Tags: rsync, ssh-keys

I have just attempted to copy some files to a remote host using rsync, and after doing that I can no longer SSH into the remote host.

The command I used was:

```
rsync -av /foo/bar/ user@remotehost:.
```

Everything appeared to work fine, but now my remote host will not accept my private key file. I suspect the home folder, or at the very least the .ssh folder has been wiped, but I can't work out why.

I found a similar post below from back in 2015. Has anyone else experienced this? The local host was a Linux Mint 18.3 VM installed in ProxMox, and the remote machine was a physical Linux Mint 18.3 machine.

Similar issue [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29777241/cannot-ssh-into-remote-machine-after-rsync).

Answer (score 7):

OK I found out what was happening. The home drive and .ssh folder were all fine, nothing had been wiped as I had originally thought. So I ran sshd in debug mode using the following command:

```
# /usr/sbin/sshd -d -p 2222
```

After attempting to login via the debug port, I got this output:

```
***
debug1: temporarily_use_uid: 1000/1000 (e=0/0)
debug1: trying public key file /home/user/.ssh/authorized_keys
debug1: fd 4 clearing O_NONBLOCK
Authentication refused: bad ownership or modes for directory /home/user
debug1: restore_uid: 0/0
Failed publickey for user from 127.0.0.1 port 37422 ssh2: RSA 
SHA256:xxxx
Connection closed by 127.0.0.1 port 37422 [preauth]
***
```

*Authentication refused: bad ownership or modes for directory /home/user* was the problem. I checked the permissions of the /home/user folder and sure enough it had been changed from 755 to 777, which happened to be the same permissions as the source folder (/foo/bar)

SSHD doesn't like it when you have group write access on the home directory. The problem was fixed by changing the permissions back again:

```
# chmod 755 /home/user
```

Looking at the rsync man page:

*A trailing slash on the source changes this behaviour to avoid creating an additional directory level at the destination. You can think of a trailing / on a source as meaning "copy the contents of this directory" as opposed to "copy the directory by name", **but in both cases the attributes of the containing directory are transferred to the containing directory on the destination.** In other words, each of the following commands copies the files in the same way, including their setting of the attributes of /dest/foo*

*rsync -av /src/foo /dest*

*rsync -av /src/foo/ /dest/foo*

So to avoid changing the destination directory permissions and potentially messing up SSH authentication:

```
rsync -av /foo/bar/* user@remotehost:.
```

Or.. in my case it was actually preferable to do:

```
rsync -av /foo/bar user@remotehost:.
```

Hope that helps someone else!

Comment: I had the _exact_ same problem.  It was...very interesting.  The permissions on the user directory being rsync'd _to_ were changed to 775, unlike how yours were changed to 777.  Anyway I ssh'd to this box with a _different_ user I _previously_ setup and confirmed that the permissions had changed.  The offending rsync command I was using was `rsync -avz "$1" $USER@${HOST[0]}:~` which I changed to `rsync -avz "$1" "$USER@${HOST[0]}:/home/$USER/$2"`.  I _think_ the tilde `~` was the offending component, but really I'm not sure.  If anyone knows the truth I'd be grateful to read it :-).

Comment: This is insane. Good troubleshooting.

Comment: ..........WHY DO YOU HAVE GROUP / WORLD READ ON USER HOME DIRECTORIES!!?!  So many keys and important things are stored there. They should almost certainly be `700`.

Answer (score 0):

"rsync -e "ssh -i testing.pem" -rlpEAXogDtSzh -P -x --exclude-from="$EXCLUDEFILE" --rsync-path="sudo rsync" --verbose --progress / azureuser@$TARGETVM:/home/azureuser/testing-folder" you have to change the destination path then it won't change the directories permission follow this tutorial use pem key file for migration if you are not able to login using root or password
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/archive/blogs/keithmayer/cloud-to-cloud-migrating-ubuntu-linux-virtual-machines-to-microsoft-azure-from-amazon-aws

Comment: In order to help OP understand your response more easily, you should format the commands using backtick (`). One backtick for a single line, three in a row for a group of code.